# SSRS 2016 Report Portal - KPI option no available in drop down

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

Is there a way to enable the KPI selection in reporting services 2016 web portal?

I eagerly wanted to try this feature, I then wasted 2 hours looking for it, still haven't found it. In most examples it seems to be under the "New" drop down.

[image]

I'm on the home portal page , I did create a dataset and datasource. Still no KPI option. I've remoted onto the host server, the user has System Administrator and System User rights in SSRS.

Comment: Great question, I spent quite a bit of time and the answer allowed me to realize that I had accidentally installed the wrong edition. Once I reinstalled the SQL Server with Enterprise, this option came up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

KPIs are an Enterprise feature. They are only available in the Enterprise and Developer Editions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt742500.aspx

You will also need to do two things in order to have KPIs show up in the "New" dropdown.

1. You must have Content Manager or Publisher privileges in the folder you will be creating the KPIs in.
2. You must have at least Browse privileges to a shared data source and shared data set.  These do not have to be in the same folder as where you want to publish the KPI.

Keep in mind local admin isn't a privilege/role. I set up my own SSRS 2016 instance. But I still needed to add my self(and the admin group) to the Content Manager role.